# Finding alternate jack points in a Honda Insight

Tags: honda, safety, jack

I'm trying to locate an alternate jack and lift point for my Honda Insight. I'm trying to lift the entire front end of the vehicle so I can put the stands under the pinch welds near the wheels. I can't put the jack under the pinch welds and put the stands on it because the jack is too big.

There doesn't seem to be a clearly marked jack point or tow hook in the front of the Insight (I think Hondas generally have an arrow to denote the front jack point). The only points in the manual are the reinforced pinch welds.

I'm not entirely sure which parts of the subframe or control arm to choose to stick the jack under. I took a few pictures with a few potential options.

[image: Subframe and control arm]

[image: Subframe points]

[image: Potential point]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first picture where you have the orange circled item ... just to the left of it (in the picture) there is a large bolt which attaches the circled item to the body. This would probably be a good lift point. I've found that anywhere which is going to be used as a bolted mount point is going to be very sturdy. If you are worried about marring the bolt, put a piece of wood between the jack and the bolt head. This will provide enough protection by spreading the load over a larger area as well as a softer, malleable point to jack from. It looks as though there is two of these, one on each side of the vehicle which you can lift from.

Comment: I ended up sticking a piece of wood between the bolt and the jack and it was perfectly fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Most modern vehicles are built in the expectation that when being worked on they will be in a repair shop, equipped with service ramps. The is usually a two post ramp, which has four jacking arms. Their arms are placed under the seams of the vehicle, or specific lifting points on them, to raise the vehicle. If you do not have a ramp available, the next best option is two vehicle jacks, one each side. Jack them gradually and equally to raise the vehicle to fit the stands. The third option is with a single jack. Jack each side a small amount at a time, adjusting the stand heights as you go.